# Refresh values in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to write validators for my form fields.

In my case I have a page with a hidden edit form and list that displays usernames. When clicking on one of the usernames in the list then an edit field is displayed below which contains a check-unique directive.

I want to parse parameter values to the directive as soon I open my edit form. But of course they will not be updated in the directive as the page has compiled already and the values are only parsed to the directive during load of the page. So my attr.checkUnique value is empty even though I want to parse the username as attribute value.

Here is my fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/charms/r3ajt/28/

Does somebody know if the directive can be refreshed somehow to take over the new parameters while executing the "openEdit" method?

Or is there any other clever way how to overcome this issue? Somehow I'm stuck here.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HandleCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="u in users">
    {{u.username}}<button ng-click="openEdit({{u.id}})">Edit</button><br/>
</div>
<form ng-show="showNew" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="username"/>
</form>
<form ng-show="showEdit" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.username" check-unique="{{user.username}}"/>
</form>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('HandleCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
$scope.showNew = false;
$scope.showEdit = false;

$scope.user = {};
$scope.users = [];

$scope.users[0] = {username:'matt', id:1};
$scope.users[1] = {username:'bob', id:2};
$scope.users[2] = {username:'tom', id:3};

$scope.openEdit = function(id) {
    $scope.showEdit = true;
    $scope.user = $scope.users[id-1];
};
}])
.directive('checkUnique', [function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        console.log("I want username but value is empty: " + attr.checkUnique);
    }
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve correctly...

You need to `watch` for a model change in your directive. Try this:

```
.directive('checkUnique', [function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch('user.username', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                console.log('Username selected is ' + newValue);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

As your directive is sharing it's parent's scope (as specified in your directive definition) then you can directly access 'user.username'.

Answer (score 0):

You can access you model by using ctroller option and what when the model is updated. Here's a full exemple of what you can do and how to access your model.

```
.directive('checkUnique', [function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function(nv) { // Don't watch ctrl.$viewValue cause it won't watch.
                console.log("I want username but value is empty: " + nv); // When 
                if (nv.indexOf('is magic') === -1) { // Don't want infinite loop.
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(nv +  ' is magic'); // Set a new value to model.
                }

                console.log('My current value is ' + ctrl.$viewValue); // Accessing model scope.
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here's your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3ajt/30/) updated.